# What's the probability the cumulative average of multiple gaussian variables exceed a certain value?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Consider a number $n$ of independent, normally distributed variables $Y_1$, $Y_2$, ..., $Y_n$.
Consider also the $n$ variables defined by the average of the last $h$ terms, $X_h = \frac{\sum^{n}_{k = n -h + 1} Y_k}{h}$ for $h \in \{1,.., n\}$. The variables $\sqrt{h}X_h$ are normally distributed.

I'd like to understand what is the probability of having $P\{\sqrt{h}X_h > T \text{ or } \sqrt{h-1}X_{h-1} > T \text{ or .. or } X_1>T \}$, in words having one or more of the $\sqrt{h}X_h$ to output above a threshold value.

Do you have any reference or suggestions about this problem?
I can work out the $n = 2$ case through [geometry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYoA1.jpg) working on the expression $P\{Y_1 + Y_2 > \sqrt{2}T \, |\, Y_1<T \}$. However I soon get lost into integral hell when dimension increases.

Thank you

---

EDIT:

I add my solution when $n = 2$. As remarked by @ConMan, the probability we are looking for is equal to one minus the probability for all $\sqrt{h}X_h$ to output under threshold $T$, so:

$$ P = 1 - p(Y_1 + Y_2 < \sqrt{2}T\,|\,Y_1< T)p(Y_1<T) $$

We can calculate the term $ p(Y_1 + Y_2 < \sqrt{2}T\,|\,Y_1< T) $ geometrically (see [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYoA1.jpg)), through:

$$ p(Y_1 + Y_2 < \sqrt{2}T\,|\,Y_1< T)  = \int_{-\infty}^{\sqrt{2}T -T} \text{d}x N(x) + \int^{\infty}_{\sqrt{2}T -T}\text{d}x N(x)\Big[ 1 - \int^{T}_{\sqrt{2}T -x}\text{d}y N(y)\Big]=\\
 = 1 - \int^{\infty}_{\sqrt{2}T -T}\text{d}x N(x)\Big( F(T) - F(\sqrt{2} T - x) \Big)=\\
 = 1 - \Phi(T)\big(1 - \Phi(\sqrt{2}T - T)\big) + \int^{\infty}_{\sqrt{2}T -T}\text{d}x N(x) \Phi(\sqrt{2} T - x) $$

Naming $H(T)$ the last integral term, the probability we are looking for become:

$$P = 1 - \Phi(T)\Big( 1 -\Phi(T)\big(1-\Phi(\sqrt{2}T - T)\big) + H(T) \Big)$$

If $T = 3$, we find a probability $P \sim 2.5\%$ which implies a value larger than the probability $1 - \Phi(T)$ by a factor $\frac{P(T)}{1-\Phi(T)} \sim 1.823$.

Where we noted with $\Phi$ and $N$ the normal partition and probability density function respectively.
This seems confirmed by simulations, in python:

```
import scipy.stats as sts
import numpy as np

N = 1000000
M = 2
host_matrix = np.zeros((N,M))

for n in range(N):
    arr = sts.norm(0).rvs(M)
    wind = np.cumsum(arr)/np.sqrt(np.arange(M) + 1)
    host_matrix[n] = wind
```

Here a routine for calculating the value of the formula above:

```
def fp_prb(thr):
    import scipy.integrate as integrate
    def hard_term_f(x, T):
        return sts.norm.pdf(x)*sts.norm.cdf(sqrt(2)*T - x)
    
    hard_term = integrate.quad(lambda x: hard_term_f(x,thr),thr*(sqrt(2) - 1),+np.inf)[0]
    F_t = F(thr)
    F_sqrt = F(thr*(sqrt(2)-1))
    
    prb = 1 - F_t*( 1 - F_t*(1 - F_sqrt) + hard_term )    
    return  prb
```

The observed frequency and probability ratio can be computed through:

```
thr = 3

no_fp = len(np.argwhere((host_matrix[:,0] < thr ) & (host_matrix[:,1] < thr )))
fp_freq =  1 - no_fp/N
norm_freq = 1 - sts.norm.cdf(thr)
print('FP frequency: {:.4f}'.format(fp_freq))
print('Normal detections frequency: {:.4f}'.format(norm_freq))
print('Ratio: {:.3f}'.format(fp_freq/norm_freq))
```

An example output:

```
FP frequency: 0.0025
Normal detections frequency: 0.0013
Ratio: 1.841
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to do all the calculations assuming you're taking the average of the first $h$ variables rather than the last, because it makes the algebra a little neater without really changing the results. Also, I'm going to assume you always look at the full sequence of $n$ variables, since you can always just drop off the ones you're not working with and set $n = h$ to get the same effect.

The first step is to flip that probability around. Instead of looking at "the probability that at least one is greater", instead look at "the probability that all of them are less", i.e. $P(X_1 \leq T \land X_2 \leq T \land \ldots \land X_h \leq T)$, because these two probabilities are complements and hence will add to 1, but this one is easier to work with.

Second, let's write everything in vectors.

$\mathbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix} X_1 \\ X_2 \\ \vdots \\ X_n \end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
& & &\ddots \\
\frac{1}{n} & \frac{1}{n} & \frac{1}{n} & \ldots & \frac{1}{n} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} Y_1 \\ Y_2 \\ \vdots \\ Y_n \end{bmatrix} = \mathbf{MY} $

So our probability becomes $P(\mathbf{X} \leq T\mathbf{1}_n) = P(\mathbf{MY} \leq T \mathbf{1}_n) = P(\mathbf{Y} \leq T\mathbf{M}^{-1}\mathbf{1}_n)$.

So now we just have to invert that matrix. I am going to propose, and suggest that you prove for yourself, that:

$\mathbf{M}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 2 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -2 & 3 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
 & & & \ddots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & -(n-1) & n \end{bmatrix}$

Which, neatly, means that $\mathbf{M}^{-1} \mathbf{1}_n = \mathbf{1}_n$, and so our probability is literally just $P(\mathbf{X} \leq T\mathbf{1}_n) = P(\mathbf{Y} \leq T\mathbf{1}_n) = P(Y_1 \leq T \land Y_2 \leq T \land \ldots \land Y_n \leq T) = P(Y_1 \leq T)P(Y_2 \leq T) \ldots P(Y_n \leq T) = \Phi(T)^n$ because the $Y_i$ are all independent.

So, the probability that all of the averages are less than the threshold is $\Phi(T)^n$, meaning that the probability that *at least one* crosses the threshold is $1 - \Phi(T)^n$.

Comment: I did have the idea of trying to "uncorrelate" the $X_i$ in the manner you did here, but without trying to do it I never would've guessed it would work out so clean.

Comment: Also I find it quite counterintuitive that the probability that this vector of correlated N(0,1) variables has a component past $T$ is the same as the probability that the same number of independent N(0,1) variables do the same. Is there some heuristic explanation?

Comment: @ConMan first of all a giant THANK YOU for the huge head-up. I love your approach and will attempt to work on it myself. However there is a problem with the matrix $M$: all it's elements should in fact be under square root. This seems to lead to an underestimate of the probability of passing a threshold. I have added my attempt to solution in the main post for the case $n = 2$ and some python code for simulating this problem.

Comment: @Ian yesterday i went to bed and forgot to thank you too for the suggestions. I liked the idea of checking Wiener processes since this is a problem which has a foot in control theory indeed. However, being not very proficient with that math, it is hard to me to reason on it properly. If it can be of any help, I've added my solution to the case $N = 2$ and some python code for simulating the problem to the main post.

Comment: @deppep I think you can just follow this procedure with the correction with the square roots and get a result in the form $1-\prod_{i=1}^n \Phi(x_i)$ for some explicitly defined $x_i$.